# file deleting error inside many directories in Windows 7 Professional

Tags: windows-7

I created directories and files as you see here with a java code by mistake:

```
 D:\...\storages\1\1\1\1\1\1\1\1\1\1\1\1\1\1\1\1\1\1\1\1\1\1\1\1\1\1\1\1\1\1\1\1\1\1\1\1\1\1\1\1\1\1\1\1\1\1\1\1\1\1\1\1\1\1\asd\assets\1\Back-Up\2011_0~1\Resources\ some files here.
```

and now I am not able to delete them. I got the error

> The source file name(s) are larger than is supported by the file
>   system. Try moving to a location which has a shorter path name, or try
>   renaming to shorter name(s) before attempting this operation."

The fileassassin couldn't see the files with file Explorer window and the unlocker program lost the responsibility after a while. Both didn't solve the problem. Do you have another idea ?

I use Windows 7 Professional.

Answer (score 0):

Use robocopy.

`robocopy *c:\an_empty_directory* *c:\base_of_nested* /purge`

Comment: do u mean robocopy D:1\ D:\...\storages\

D:1\ an empty directory and "storages" has all nested directories.
i tried like that and it was doing something infinitely. how much time would it take? 10 mins?

Comment: No, your empty directory is the source.  and d:\1 is the base of nested.  The purge switch basically deletes anything in the target that isn't in the source.  If you specify an empty source, then robocopy deletes everything in the target, which is **the nested directories.*  If you do it the **other way around**, **it just copies all the nested folders.**

Comment: i have an empty directory as "D:\storages" and nested ones under "D:\...\storages" it goes "1\1\1\1\1..." in the "D:\...\storages"
and my command is like that  " robocopy D:storages D:\...\storages "
but it didnt work anyway.

Answer (score 0):

download this file from this given url, install this in your machine and do right click on file or directory -> select unlocker option -> take any action that your wants.

http://www.softpedia.com/get/System/System-Miscellaneous/Unlocker.shtml